# How can I convert a table column to a row?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a tab-separated (`\t`) file with two columns:

```
a_1  T_b
a_2  T_c
a_2  T_d
a_2  T_e
a_3  T_f
a_4  B_a
a_4  B_b
```

I now want to convert that to a file with one sample per row and all values for each sample as a space-separated 3nd field on the same row, like this:

```
a_1  T_b
a_2  T_c T_d T_e
a_3  T_f 
a_4  B_a B_b
```

I just mastered the conversion from the second file to the first file by awk. So can you give me some advice, forgive me my poor unix skills. thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want advice on? Do you have `awk` code that works and you want to improve it, or do you want us to give you the awk code?

Comment: Was the indentation of the input and output (which is now removed by terdon's edit) intentional? Idea for algorithm: Check if the 1st field has changed. If yes, print any saved line and save the current input line, if not, append the 2nd field to the saved line, separated by space or `OFS`. At the end print the saved line if any.

Comment: Yes, i want to get the awk way,  but i only konw the way that covert second file to first file   such like awk -F\\t 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {n=split($2,aa," ");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {$2=aa[i]; printf "%s\n" $0 }}'

Comment: Does the output order of the first fields matter? Is the input guaranteed to all fit in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
      { 
        $1 in a? a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2 : a[$1]=$2 
      }
      END{ 
        for(i in a){print i"\t"a[i]} 
      }' file

a_1 T_b
a_2 T_c T_d T_e
a_3 T_f
a_4 B_a B_b
```

The idea here is that we create the associative array `a` whose keys are the first field, the sample name. Then, for each line, if this sample is already present as a key, we set its value to this line's second field and, if it is not, we append the current 2nd field to the existing value. The same thing could be written more verbosely like this:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
      { 
        if($1 in a){ a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2 }
        else       { a[$1]=$2 }
      }
      END{ 
        for(i in a){print i"\t"a[i]} 
      }' file
```

Comment: It's useful, Sir, but it generated the file contains multiple columns separated by (\t). I only want to get the file with two columns, and the second column is separated by blank.

Comment: Oh, OK, that's even easier then @loki. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, i get the righ way, i have notice that " a[$1]=a[$1]" \t"$2 ", "print i,a[i]}" in your initial script. Anyway, I learned a lot, thanks for your valuable advice！

Comment: `$1 in a? a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2 : a[$1]=$2` can be written more concisely and without so much duplication as `a[$1]=($1 in a? a[$1]" " : "") $2`

Comment: Nice, thanks @EdMorton!

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `datamash` to group by the first tab-delimited column and collapse the other column:

```bash
$ datamash groupby 1 collapse 2 <file
a_1     T_b
a_2     T_c,T_d,T_e
a_3     T_f
a_4     B_a,B_b
```

This assumes that the file is sorted on the first field.  If it is not, then use `datamash` with its `-s` (`--sort`) option, or pipe the data in to `datamash` via `sort`.

In case you want the "sub-fields" of the second field delimited by space instead of commas, replace the commas with space using e.g. `awk`:

```bash
$ datamash groupby 1 collapse 2 <file | awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { gsub(","," ",$2) }; 1'
a_1     T_b
a_2     T_c T_d T_e
a_3     T_f
a_4     B_a B_b
```

Comment: I will try it, i often receive your useful advice, Mr. Kusalananda. really really appreciate it

Comment: I expect you could just pipe the datamash output to `tr ',' ' '`. The code already assumes no `,`s in the 2nd input col, may as well extend that assumption to the first input col too.

Answer (score 1):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -e 'my %hash; for lines>>.words() {%hash.append( .[0] => .[1] )}; .say for %hash.sort;'
```

OR

```
raku -e 'my %hash; for lines.map(*.words) -> ($k,$v) {%hash.append: $k => $v }; .say for %hash.sort;'
```

Briefly, hash-functionalities built into Raku are used to address this problem. Lines are read and broken into (whitespace-separated) `words`. Words are appended to hash `%hash`, with the first column becoming a key, and the second column becoming values. Raku's `=>` "fat arrow" operator is used to construct key-value pairs, and the `append` routine accumulates values based on key (no hash can have duplicate keys).

Sample Input:

```
a_1  T_b
a_2  T_c
a_2  T_d
a_2  T_e
a_3  T_f
a_4  B_a
a_4  B_b
```

Sample Output:

```
a_1 => T_b
a_2 => [T_c T_d T_e]
a_3 => T_f
a_4 => [B_a B_b]
```

Change `.say` in the code above to `.put` to get `\t` tab separated output.  Or define your own field separator(s): example below with the first column separated from the second by 4-spaces, and `value`s of the second column separated by commas (change to spaces if so desired):

```
~$ raku -e 'my %hash; for lines.map(*.words) -> ($k,$v) {%hash.append: $k => $v }; for %hash.sort {put .key, "    ", .value.join(",")};'
a_1    T_b
a_2    T_c,T_d,T_e
a_3    T_f
a_4    B_a,B_b
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap#Mutable_hashes_and_immutable_maps
https://docs.raku.org/routine/=%3E
https://raku.org